# Google chrome select box selections are whitened out in iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, select, iframe

There is a bug with Google Chrome. As result of the bug the html element select values in page, when it is injected throw Iframe over http/https (when you inject Iframe from file system, it works fine) are whitened out in sub-monitors.

To reproduce the issue, you need at least 2 monitors with 2 different resolution. You have to mark as main monitor, the monitor with higher resolution.

Then you need to host a index.html somewhere with following content (local IIS for example):

> ```
> <html> <head> </head> <body>
> <div>
>     <select>
>         <option value=""></option>
>         <option value="2">Visa</option>
>         <option value="3">AmericanExpress</option>
>         <option value="4">Bonus</option>
>         <option value="5">DinersClub</option>
>         <option value="6">Discover</option>
>         <option value="7">MasterCard</option>
>     </select>
> </div> </body> </html>
> ```

And then you can inject it throw iframe to another index.html:

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>       <iframe width="1000px" height="500px" src="http://exmapleUrl" />
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

And now when you open the last index.html with google chrome browser in sub-monitor which resolution is lower then main monitors, you should see the bug.

The bug disappears when browser window is resized or zoomed.

I did report it to google using "report an issue" feature in google chrome browser. But meanwhile, could anyone have any idea how to resolve it from my side ? Is there any way to perform zoom-in/zoom-out action with JavaScript in background so user wouldn't notice ?

[image: Bug screenshot]

Comment: In Chrome version 78.0.3904.70 I'm getting the alternatives, but a way too big dropdown background.

Comment: Visible here: http://jsfiddle.net/QBjkB/